# Pytesseract image to text problem in Python

Tags: python, python-tesseract

Please check the following image:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqom8.png)

I am using the following code to extract text from the image.

```
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

But the result is showing different than the original one:

It is showing the following result:

```
+BuFl
```

But it should be:

```
+Bu#L
```

I don't know what the problem is. I am pretty new in Pytesseract.

Is there anyone who can help me to sort out the problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

One way of solving is applying [otsu-thresholding](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html)

Otsu's method automatically finds the threshold value unlike global thresholding.

The result of applying Otsu's threshold will be:

[image]

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract


img = cv2.imread("Tqom8.png")  # Load the image
img = cv2.resize(img, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert to gray
thr = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 128, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
txt = pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, config='--psm 6')
print(pytesseract.__version__)
print(txt)
```

Result:

```
0.3.8
+Bu#L
```

Also make sure to read the [Improving the quality of the output](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html)

Comment: Thanks it works but not for all the images.